# Word for "A person who has a busy life but still manages to do everything on time"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a suitable word for
"A person who has a busy life but still manages to do everything on time"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Corner-cutter. :)

Comment: This is a hard question to answer because there is nothing about a "busy life" that inherently interferes with doing things "on time". One would just use the generic term "punctual."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Many words capture the "busy" side or the "punctual" side, but those qualities are often mutually exclusive in people.  I can certainly be a multitasker yet show up slightly late for all my appointments.  :-(  On the other hand, I can easily be punctual when I do not have a busy life.

The closest word I can think of that *might* suggest both qualities is **expeditious**, as in, "My mother is known for her expeditious handling of matters."

It means "done with speed and efficiency", which *suggests* the person may be both on-time and at least *capable* of handling a busy life, though they may not actually have one. So this is also not the perfect word, but maybe it is helpful.

Comment: this is the closest term which i have got. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best generic term would be **well organised**, although depending on the context one of these might also be appropriate: prolific, driven, a machine, in-the-zone, achieving a good 'flow', over-achiever, workaholic.